# How to get the object from another dart file

Tags: flutter, dart

I have two files named 'main.dart' and 'arview.dart'

`main.dart` includs `arview.dart`

There is class named `TopPage` in

`main.dart`

```
import 'arview.dart';

class TopPage extends StatefulWidget {
....
```

then I want to get the `TopPage` class in `arview.dart`.

```
class ArViewState extends State<ArViewWidget> with WidgetsBindingObserver {
....
    return Navigator.pushReplacement(context,
          NoAnimationMaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => TopPage()));
```

How can I access TopPage from 'arview.dart'???

```
[   +4 ms] lib/arview.dart:188:37: Error: The method 'TopPage' isn't defined for the class 'ArViewState'.
[        ]  - 'ArViewState' is from 'package:wikitude_flutter_app/arview.dart' ('lib/arview.dart').
[        ] Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'TopPage'.
[        ]               builder: (context) => TopPage()));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be importing `main.dart`(which contains `TopPage`) to the place you want to use it(`arview.dart`), not the other way around.

```dart
import 'main.dart';

class ArViewState extends State<ArViewWidget> with WidgetsBindingObserver {
....
    return Navigator.pushReplacement(context,
          NoAnimationMaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => TopPage()));
```

Comment: Thank you ,it works!! perfect for me. it might be quite too silly and basic question... I expected something like global variables...